# Check a column if doesn't exists in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to check a column if it doesn't exists in `SqlDataReader`. I tried using `reader.IsDBNull` and `reader.GetOrdinal`, but still getting error "Index Out of range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this method**

```
  public static class DataRecordExtensions
        {
            public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
            {
                for (int i=0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

try this

```
public static bool HasColumn(DbDataReader Reader, string ColumnName) { 
    foreach (DataRow row in Reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows) { 
        if (row["ColumnName"].ToString() == ColumnName) 
            return true; 
    } //Still here? Column not found. 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: I have already used `GetName` but still getting the same error.